# Calculating Distance and Route using Google Maps API Webservices without showing Data on Google Map

Tags: web-services, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

UseCase :

We are working on a mobile App use case to calculate the users distance from his current location (while  Moving)  to specific destination (Eg: To Airport) by using his location coordinates collected periodically in background of the app

In order to achieve this we are opting for Server Side Google Maps API Web Services solution , which can calculate the Distance of the user from collected location coordinates from users device

For doing so we in server side we have noticed a restriction from Google Maps API WebServices ,that calculated distance data should only be used in conjunction with Google Maps rendered  with data

So our Question is : Can we calculate the distance using Google API Web services without rendering the data on Google Maps in Server side Web App or console ,but after calculating the distance in server side , embedding the google static map best route link as a Push Notification message to Users Device ?

Reference to the Restriction we noticed in below link : 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/

[image: Google API Restriction !!!]

Awaiting for Quick Response !!! Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal issues

Comment: No!The Point is that is there any way we can calculate the distance in server side and send that data to mobile as a static link to be rendered in the google maps etc ...

Comment: @Fedrick were you able to solve this. I am also with the same need.